# Extract a file from zip inside 7z

Tags: python, zip, 7zip, py7zr, py7zlib

I have a 7z file that contains folders and can also have .zip archives inside it.
Given a filepath inside the zip archive, I would like to extract only this file without its path. So far, all I managed to do is to extract a file that's inside a folder using the following command:

`7z e <file.7z> */<some_folder>/my_file.txt -r -aou -y`

However, when I replaced `<some_folder>` with the name of a zip file, it didn't work.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? I'm looking for a solution using either the command-line (cmd) or Python.
I'm aware of the `extract()` function in py7zr, but it extracts the file with its directory structure, which is not what I need.

all I managed to do is to extract a file that's inside a folder using the following command:

`7z e <file.7z> */<some_folder>/my_file.txt -r -aou -y`

However, when I replaced `<some_folder>` with the name of a zip file, it didn't work.